# How to make world Background not affect objects in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, reflection

so, say for example, I want to make a spinning Minecraft cake in blender cycles, and I want a blue, unaffected background from the light, so I have the world background be blue, and it reflects onto the cake, how would I make it so the objects in the scene are not affected by background reflections and whatnot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Light Path* node's *Is Camera Ray* output yields a mask that can be used to change the look of the world when viewed directly from the camera.

[image: 1]

Transparent materials such as a window will not work with this since any transmitted light is indirect. *bummer*

[image: 2]

Ways around this issue include masking, transparent film, and making use of the other outputs of the *Light Path* node.